# How to prevent execution of javascript from a browser's address bar?

Tags: javascript

If I go to [this](http://www.bloganything.net/731/cool-javascript-tricks-for-internet-browsers) page and then delete the url from my browser's address bar, and then enter

```
javascript:document.getElementById('rsidebar').value='dsf';
```

The whole part refreshes. How can I prevent a page from refreshing when executing javascript from the address bar?

Also, are there any other techniques to manipulate a page without having access to the page source like the above method?

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot stop the user from manipulating the DOM.

You don't need to worry about people manipulating the DOM from the client-side. These changes only effect their local experience. They aren't actually affecting your site for other users.

You can easily manipulate the DOM using tools like Firebug, IEDeveloperToolbar, or Greasemonkey (Javascript engine).

Comment: yes i know, i just thirst for knowledge.  any other techinque can do it for local experience?

Comment: =) i also know can use tool like what u mentioned. =) what if using naked browser without tool. possible? iframe ?

Comment: And regarding an answer to -your initial question- please see my answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

1. When you do `javascript:stuff();` and `stuff()` produces a return value, the whole page is replaced by it. You can prevent that by using `javascript:void(stuff());` or `javascript:stuff();void(0);`
2. Already answered by others :)

Comment: `javascript:void(stuff());` is the key to question one

Comment: Havenard, you here?!?! A remark,  you don't need to use parentheses when using void, it is an operator, so javacript:void doStuff(); is right too.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1: I think this isn't possible because the browser runs every website in its own 'sandbox'

For Q2: I believe [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) will let you execute javascript on any webpage...

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:  As the earlier responders said, nothing you can do I don't think.

Question 2:  Check out [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), some very cool things can be done by running your own JavaScript against pages from various sites.  People have written bookmarklets to highlight things on the page, put warning indicators next to links that will open in a new window, or go to aPDF, etc.